# Mobile number validation issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, validation, uitextfield

I am developing an iOS application in which I have to Validate user's Phone number when he is typing.

Here is the conditions:

```
  1. Starting number can only be 9,8,7
  2. Length = 10
  3. Only Numbers
```

If users enters any other character then nothing should be printed on textfield.

I am writing all my code in `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` method.

I have successfully implemented these three conditions. I am **stuck** in this fourth condition:

```
**4. User enters 9834 then he jumps to first position and then types 19834**
```

I am not able to handle this.
How can I know the users has typed some numbers and now he is typing on first position. So that I can return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `range` to find the location where user is editing.

use `range.location` or `range.length` to validate.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if(range.location==0){

        if ([string isEqualToString:@"9"] || [string isEqualToString:@"8"] || [string isEqualToString:@"7"]) {
            return YES;
        }
        else{
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thnx bro... I doesn't know about this location property .

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with [libPhoneNumber](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS).  If the link is broken, just google for it.  It's a library from Google, originally written for Android.  It's been ported to several languages, including Objective-C.

Anything you come up with will be missing corner cases and all sorts of rules that libPhoneNumber handles for you.  This is one area where "don't roll your own" is the way to go.